# GLPI and OCS - creating groups for inventory and assigning devices to users

Tags: asset-management

I'm using GLPI in combination with OCS for inventory in our company.  Our company has different sections so I'm interested if someone knows if it is possible [and how to do it if its possible] to create different groups in GLPI or OCS  so I could group stored computers by different parts of company. Also, is it possible to assign devices to  particular users? E.G. I would add digital camera section in GLPI  and when some employ takes that camera I would mark that camera is currently being used by that user.

I'm open to other suggestions regarding inventory software, but it must be FOSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm kind of confused by the question as this capability is not hidden in GLPI in any way. But here's one way to approach the subject:

**Groups**
The way we do this is to set the `tag` in OCSInventory to the group name, and then configure GLPI to use the tag value for the group.

For example, in /etc/ocsinventory-agent/ocsinventory-agent.cfg

```
tag = unix
```

Then in GLPI go to `setup` -> `OCSNG Mode` -> `General Informations`, and change `Group` to `TAG`.
This will make it so that when machines are imported into GLPI, they have their group set properly. In the above example, its just saying that the machine belongs to the 'unix' group.
You can also manually assign ownership of the machine by changing the 'Group' value when viewing the device. We prefer to do it through OCSNG so that we can be absolutely sure that when a machine is imported, it has the group ownership assigned.

[image: group]

**Assignment**
For the second part, GLPI has 2 possible fields. `Technician in charge of the hardware` and `User`. These should be usable for what you want. If not can you explain why?

[image: user]

Comment: Hi, this helped. Do you maybe know how to get IP addresses imported in from  OCS ?

Comment: @Celestin It should be done automatically. You can find it under the "Connections" tab.

Comment: Hi, I can't find any information related to network under that tab :( Also software is missing.  I'v checked under OCS settings in GLPI if IP is selected and it is.  Also I have tried turning on and off OCS directory in GLPI but without luck.

Comment: @Celestin its been a long time since I've configured GLPI, but try going to setup -> ocsng mode -> general information and make sure `ip` is `yes`.

Answer (score 1):

Open-AudIT v2 (OAv2) does the assignment and grouping out of the box.

Assigning a PC is simply placing it in a "group". A PC can belong to more than one group and a group can be created based on any audited attribute. IE - a group for all systems in the 192.168.1.xxx based subnet. Some of the systems in that group may also be in a group containing all PCs that belong to finance. Etc, etc, etc.

You can also designate a particular person responsible for a particular PC, as well.

Free and open source.

http://www.open-audit.org

What's on your network?